# Snappy Ubuntu Core, no Docker or Owncloud in 'store'

Tags: ubuntu-core

I downloaded the image of Snappy Ubuntu Core for the Beaglebone Black, Alpha 2. When I now try to install Docker or Owncloud it cannot be found. Nor are the apps/framework available through the WebDM 'app store'. Numerous guides online refer to both these applications as being available already, some from January some from all way back in December.

I should add that I am using the latest available version of Ubuntu Core (there are no updates when checking - updating has worked in the past, so that is not the issue) with the build number 2. Which is odd, often in guides people are using 1XX etc. I am also using the 'channel' (which I assume is the 'repository') ubuntu-core/devel. Also, there are other apps available (5-6 meaningless example apps) but not Docker or Owncloud.

Does the precompiled image for the Beaglebone have a different repository than the regular Snappy Ubuntu Core, or have they been pulled?

EDIT: I was looking for information as to what happened to the packages on the armhf platform

Answer (score 2):

At least the 15.04 release (dated 13-Nov-2015) has docker available if you do a 'snappy search docker'.

ownCloud has two packages: a snappy package and a docker package, but the former is not available for BeagleBone Black.

And after you install docker, you can find ownCloud as a docker package. It's interesting that it doesn't show up before installing docker.

Comment: Very interesting, I have since I asked this question found Owncloud in the store.  I hadn't realized it popped up after I installed docker. Docker is registered as a framework, so I guess that apps depending on a framework won't show up until it is installed.

Comment: Now if only somebody teach me how to use the Docker package of ownCloud in BBB. Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The packages are still available, but only for the amd64 architecture:

```
    $ curl -s https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/search?q=docker | jq ._embedded
{
  "clickindex:package": [
    {
      "publisher": "Kevin Glavin",
      "name": "com.ubuntu.developer.archen.swarm",
      "title": "Docker Swarm",
      "icon_url": "https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/site_media/appmedia/2014/12/swarm.png",
      "price": 0,
      "content": "application",
      "ratings_average": 0,
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/package/com.ubuntu.developer.archen.swarm"
        }
      },
      "architecture": [
        "amd64"
      ],
      "prices": {}
    },
    {
      "publisher": "Canonical",
      "name": "com.ubuntu.snappy.owncloud",
      "title": "Owncloud 7.0.3 for snappy",
      "icon_url": "https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/site_media/appmedia/2014/11/th.png",
      "price": 0,
      "content": "application",
      "ratings_average": 0,
      "version": "7.0.3.008",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/package/com.ubuntu.snappy.owncloud"
        }
      },
      "architecture": [
        "amd64"
      ],
      "prices": {}
    },
    {
      "publisher": "Canonical",
      "name": "com.ubuntu.snappy.docker",
      "title": "The docker app deployment mechanism",
      "icon_url": "https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/site_media/appmedia/2014/11/docker.png",
      "price": 0,
      "content": "application",
      "ratings_average": 0,
      "version": "1.3.3.001",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/package/com.ubuntu.snappy.docker"
        }
      },
      "architecture": [
        "amd64"
      ],
      "prices": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure as whether I should mark this as solved, although I appreciate your answer - I was looking for information as to what happened to the packages on the armhf platform. As I understand it, they have previously existed. In any case, thank you for your effort!

Answer (score -1):

OwnCloud was pulled from Ubuntu at the request of a developer. There were apparently security issues in the repo's version of ownCloud that weren't getting addressed in a timely matter, if at all.

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/owncloud-ubuntu-package-affected-by.html

Comment: the ownCloud package is in the universe repository and software in this repository WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team

Comment: Your answer relates to the owncloud package in the apt repositories, but I believe the question relates to the owncloud package for Snappy Ubuntu Core which is an entirely separate thing. Snappy Ubuntu Core is designed to address the problem that affected owncloud's packaging through apt. That the owncloud apt package was pulled is therefore not relevant to this particular question. See http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1434 for details.

Comment: You are correct, and I have since learned more about Snappy Ubuntu Core. I hope to edit my answer to more specifically address the issue.